# How to make the table pushing the footer to the end of page in Microsoft Report

Tags: vb.net, rdlc, reportviewer2008

I’m developing a Reportviewer and want to extend the table to the end of page event it has few or no record. Below is the table design in Visual Studio 2013 – VB.NET project.

[image: Table design in Visual Studio 2013 – VB.NET project]

The table has five columns: Items, descriptions, quantity, unitprice, and amount. The table body will have to extend in many pages if it has more rows. Below is the picture of printable version of my report which has only three records:

[image: My report which has only three records]

The issue is that the table cannot push footer to the end of page if there are only few records. But I want it to push the footer to the end of page like this:

[image: Table push the footer to the end of page]

In other case, if there is no row in the table, it also should push the footer to the end page like this:

[image: It also should push the footer to the end page event it has no row]

I need help to format the table to push the footer to the end of page in my report.

Comment: Can someone give me a suggestion if there is a new version of reportviewer can do these stuffs and solve this issue? Or at least please give me other method that can create a report and does satisfy the required stuffs above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many days, I have asked many people and done a lot of research. I have come out with my own solution, and that is to create a footer row for the Tablix to make up it just like report footer instead of forcing the Tablix to push the report footer to the end of page.

There are steps to make it work:

- Insert a new row under row group of Tablix. We will implement it to
  become footer row.
- Click choose the first cell of footer row (the row that you want it
  to become footer row – it should place under a row group)
- From Row Group panel (You can right click on report to show Row Group panel), click static cell of footer row.
- Open property, and set following attributes:

  *KeepTogether: True*

  *KeepWithGroup: After*

  *RepeatOnNewPage: True*

After settings are done, this row will become the footer row of Tablix and it can repeat on every page just like header row.
[image]

After making a footer row to repeat on every page, you should add a rectangle to footer row and then copy all elements from report's footer into the rectangle.
[image]

By doing this way you can solve the problem of the gap between tablix and report's footer. We trick the report footer’s elements to be parts of footer row from tablix. And it will repeat in every page just like report footer.

*Note: In case, the report has no row. You should add many empty rows to make it full page (this trick should be done in your code behind).*